# I don't have permission to access the subdirectories of a mounted share I created

Tags: mount, permissions, samba, fstab

After I mounted a domain share I tried to find duplicates with fdupes, but then I found out that I don't have permissions to the subdirectories of the share.

This is how I mounted the share:

First I made the `/media/sharename` with `mkdir`.

Then I added this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
//servername/sharename /media/sharename cifs credentials=/home/ubuntuusername/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

And I made the file with the credentials with:

```
gedit ~/.smbcredentials
```

```
username=msusername
password=mspassword
domain=DOMAIN
```

Then I used the `sudo mount -a` to mount the share.

I can reach the share (also at the GUI) but I cannot open the subdirs because I don't have permissions.

Is the share not looking at the permissions of my MS account/credentials?

Or do I have to change something in the fstab line to do that? Or is it possible to do this another way?

Comment: Maybe Linux permissions are causing the problem? Did you change the permissions of "/media/sharename" using chmod? Run 'sudo chmod -R 755 /media/sharename' if not. Are you browsing the files locally or on a networked Windows computer?

Comment: I log in with my domain account on the ubuntu machine and when I  use the command "groups" I can see the domain groups. The weird thing is that I can't access the directories from the Linux machine, but I can on a Windows machine with the same domain account.

Comment: I find out that if the group everyone or my domain user account has permissions that I can access the folder in ubuntu. But if Domain Users (or another domain group) has permissions for the folder I cannot access it in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way what worked for me! I changed the `/etc/fstab` to:

```
//servername/sharename /media/sharename cifs credentials=/home/ubuntuusername/.smbcredentials,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

Also I made my account sudoer by adding a line in `/etc/sudoers`

```
%Group ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```